# wpf designer show exception when use usercontrolbase

Tags: c#, wpf

This is UserControlBase:

```
public class UserControlBase : UserControl
{
    protected Engine m_engine = null;

    public UserControlBase() : base()
    {
        m_engine = Engine.Instance();
    }               
}
```

all user control i'm creating inharit from this class

this is wpf's xaml for EccentricityUC:

```
<local:UserControlBase x:Class="LaboratoryView.UserControls.EccentricityUC"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LaboratoryView.UserControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>

</Grid></local:UserControlBase>
```

the cs file for this xaml:

```
public partial class EccentricityUC : UserControlBase
{
    public EccentricityUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = m_engine.GetViewModel(ViewModelTypes.Eccentricity);
    }
}
```

In the wpf desginer i'm getting an exception "Cannot create an instance of "UserControlBase""

in the inner excpetion i'm getting: "No connection string named 'LaboratoryDBEntities' could be found in the application config file"
 even though, the app.config file contain this connection string (i have 2 projects, both of them contains the exact connection string)

if i remove the inharitance of usercontrolbase and just inharit from usercontrol
everything is shown again.

i can't find the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pefrom check for design time mode , so you have to write this line of code to resolve that error

```
public UserControlBase() : base()
{     
  if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
  {
   m_engine = Engine.Instance();
  }
  else 
     m_engine = new Engine();  
}
```

Comment: i dont see logic of putting -1 ..is there better way suggest